# Submit button not get re-enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails form, to which I have attached a submit handler which has a `try / catch` block and in the catch block, I display error message to the user and try to re-enable the submit button.

The button for some reason does not get re-enabled.

If I execute the same code in browser console later, the button gets re-enabled.

below is the relevant part of the code

```
function displayError(action,err){
  jQuery('input[name=commit]').removeAttr('disabled');
};

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
try {

} catch(e) {
displayError('submit', e);
}
});
```

Any help on this will be really great, Thanks.

*** Update 1

---

if i `console.log(jQuery('input[name=commit]'));` I see this

[image]

Comment: maybe there is no error? and function `displayError()` expects 2 arguments, not 1.

Comment: sorry i hastily submitted the question the arguments are correctly passed

Comment: check if your element is selected by console logging it `console.log(jQuery('input[name=commit]'))` , problem can be there otherwise all seems good

Comment: Did you tried jQuery('input[name=commit]').prop('disabled', false)?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff that did not work

Comment: what happens if you do a console.log( jQuery('input[name=commit]')) in your displayError function?

Comment: I get the submit button element

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff i have added a screenshot of what i see

Comment: In that case the prop command must work. Maybe there is some other code directly disabling the button again after enabling?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use JQuery to enable and disable buttons in a UI. Assume the id of the button is

```
id="singlebutton"
```

Using JQuery, you can disable this button via this code:

```
$('#singlebutton').prop("disabled", true);
```

This disables the button.

[image]

Likewise to enable it, use:

```
  $('#singlebutton').prop("disabled", false);
```